# Detailed breakdown of what takes Drupal so long?

Tags: 7, performance

I'm trying to figure out why my Drupal 7 take so long to render. I've installed the "performance log" module, but it was underwhelming, to say the least. It tells me a page took 2785 ms to render, with 51 ms in queries.

Now what? That's 2.7 seconds spent in PHP. Can I break it down further?

The site load is essentially zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [xhprof](http://drupal.org/project/xhprof) extension and module.

Comment: This is not exactly a piece of cake to install, but it's running now and I've got an interesting trace. Thanks!